# How to block Internet Traffic to MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, firewall, local-area-network, ufw

I have setup two KVM servers with a local hosting service. They provide me with one public IP per server. I installed mysql-server 8 on one of them. Before describing the issue, here's the result I'm hoping for: 1) The second server should be able to connect to MySQL on the first server 2) I should not be able to connect from my laptop, which isn't on the same network I.e. I only want the port (3306) to be open to the local network.

I have not yet set the MySQL bind address or created users in MySQL. But I think I need to do the firewall first based on the below.

Currently, when I run

mysql -h  -u root -p

I get the same result on my laptop and on the second server:

ERROR 1130: Host  is not allowed to connect ...

This is expected on the second server (because I haven't added user permissions in MySQL), but from my laptop I would expect it to just refuse a connection outright. If relevant, ping also receives responses from my laptop and the second server.

I think I need to use ufw to block connections from the internet. How do I do this while still allowing connections on the local network? I can run an ifconfig as well. Help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check the current status of ufw:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

By default, UFW is set to deny all incoming connections and allow all outgoing connections. If for some reason it is not, you can use this command:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
```

Next, to allow incoming MySQL connections from a specific IP address or subnet, specify the source. The subnet given to you from your service provider would work here. For example:

```
sudo ufw allow from 11.22.33.0/24 to any port 3306
```

For just a single IP address:

```
sudo ufw allow from 11.22.33.44 to any port 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

Within MySQL you can use `GRANTs` to control some or all of what you are asking for.

The source can be

- `localhost` -- referring to a socket connection on the same server
- `host.name` -- some specific host name or wild card.  `%` is dangerous
- `11.22.33.44` -- some IP address or wild card.

See the documentation for more discussion.